# Generated RSA Public and Private key modulus are the same in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I'm a newbie in Cryptography, and probably I'm asking a dumb question but I have been unable to find an answer to this. I'm generating the RSA keys in Java in an POC Android project. My purpose is to encrypt the user password with the public key and decrypt it with the private key in the server, also applying this will allow me the keep the password in the device in a more secure way (encrypted) to then use it automatically when fingerprint auth is used. I'm generating the keys with the regular Java method:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(1024);
KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = key.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = key.getPrivate();
```

Then I just log both keys to the Android Studio Logcat this way:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Public key: " + publicKey);
Log.e(TAG, "Private key: " + privateKey);
```

...and this is what I get logged:

```
10-18 15:27:17.570 22426-22426/cliu.tutorialcrypto E/AsymmetricAlgorithmRSA: Public key: OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=c1312eb5c24da9577dd40263cec233b8be40ed227b81df3c442363f1dfd5364e9e2ba96d4dd7c1011d2633d6603beb1a483b75b8af8a87b10ebe918729b6afe95893d5c93b3f99727785110f2373d20ced8bfe2421c9c682ee737c60a7c6199be3d2e7e4687d69cedc50965b8cebc4445cdfe7a13a7df5eda6a6d4304d057505,publicExponent=10001}
10-18 15:27:17.570 22426-22426/cliu.tutorialcrypto E/AsymmetricAlgorithmRSA: Private key: OpenSSLRSAPrivateCrtKey{modulus=c1312eb5c24da9577dd40263cec233b8be40ed227b81df3c442363f1dfd5364e9e2ba96d4dd7c1011d2633d6603beb1a483b75b8af8a87b10ebe918729b6afe95893d5c93b3f99727785110f2373d20ced8bfe2421c9c682ee737c60a7c6199be3d2e7e4687d69cedc50965b8cebc4445cdfe7a13a7df5eda6a6d4304d057505,publicExponent=10001}
```

Question: Why both modulus in the generated keys are equal? I assume this is not secure enough since just having the public key modulus someone could easily come up with the private key, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you generate is a key *pair* for Java. The public and private keys of the key pair *always share the same modulus*: the calculations are performed within that domain.

What is kept secure is not the modulus but the private exponent and - generally also available - the parameters required to perform the fast exponentiation using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT). These are basically the parameters such as prime P and Q used to calculate the private key and indeed the modulus.

Actually, you can use the modulus to determine that the key *pair* is unique as each key pair should have a unique modulus. This way you can also check if the public key and private key are part of the same pair - without doing signature generation / verification.

---

The private exponent and the CRT parameters are of course not printed; the modulus is enough to identify the private key and you would not want to destroy the security of the private key by printing them out.

If you want to see the private exponent and CRT parameters, then *cast* your private key to [`RSAPrivateCrtKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html) and use the getters of that class. If you just need the private exponent then casting to `RSAPrivateKey` would be less error prone. It would be a good idea to first check the type of the variable before casting unless you are OK with possible `ClassCastException`. In general the software generators will create a `RSAPrivateCrtKey` although the use of CRT parameters doesn't seem to be explicitly specified.

Note that only software based keys will probably have the getters return information so be aware that trying to get to the private parameters you may have to deal with runtime exceptions if the keys may be stored in a hardware device such as a smart card or HSM.